# How to add our own images to custom keyboard and use this keyboard in every app.?

Tags: ios, custom-keyboard

I want to add images to my custom keyboard which must me able to use each and every app while people change their keyboard to custom keyboard. This functionality like as we add emoji in our keyboard same way i want to add images of my own.

Comment: I got a simple example over here : https://github.com/tejas123/Create-Custom-Keyboard-for-iOS8

Comment: http://www.theappguruz.com/tutorial/create-custom-keyboard-ios8/ : link where nice explanation given for creating custom keyboard